# Safari 6 Search Bar Focus On New Tab/Window

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, macos

When I open new tab or window in Safari 6 in ML it doesn't focus on the search bar - what should I do to make focus automatic?

Comment: Focus is automatic for me, presuming you mean the combined search/address bar

Comment: The focus is on the new tab/ window, but not on the search/address bar.

Comment: Odd, works fine here. Where is the focus then?

Comment: Oops, on new tab it works, but try opening new window

Comment: Still works. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Safari preferences under *General* you need to choose for *Open new tabs with* either:

- Top sites or
- Empty Page

Comment: After a recent update in Safari 6, this was set back to the home page by default. Finally sorted - thanks for your answer!